# Is there a AFOAuth2Client library in Android available?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, token

I am working in a app that register a user in a specific place.
I got the client_id and the client_secret and the url, also the token url.
i have seen how simple was to use the AFOAuth2Client in Iphone and i would like to know if there is an equivalent for Android.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally not a very good idea to store secrets on a device. If you control the entire stack: client, API and AuthZ server, then make sure you use a Oauth2 flow that doesn't require that. (Or reconsider using Oauth2 altogther perhaps).

The simplest Oauth2 flows are quite simple to implement as they are straight forward HTTP requests.